# How to pass arg in Emacs abstract function

Tags: emacs, imenu, emacs-helm

I try to write a function to abstract which `helm-imenu` variant to use:

```
(defun my/helm-menu ()
  "For Org mode buffers, show Org headlines.
For programming mode buffers, show functions, variables, etc."
  (interactive)
  (cond ((derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
           (helm-org-in-buffer-headings))
        (t
           (helm-semantic-or-imenu))))
```

Though, when using it in a non-Org mode buffer, it fails, saying it needs one argument.

Indeed, `helm-semantic-or-imenu` requires `arg`.

How should I pass that?

Why is that working with a `M-x helm-semantic-or-imenu`: where is the argument?

Comment: You should try to ask that on http://emacs.stackexchange.com

Comment: You don't need to ask it on emacs.stackexchange.com. You can ask it here.

Comment: Use `C-h f helm-semantic-or-imenu` to find out what the argument is. Click the link there to go to the source definition and see what the argument is and how it is received. If that function is a command then check the `interactive` spec to see where the arg comes from. Then pass the same kind of arg to your invocation of that function.

Comment: @Drew, could you have a look at my answer to check that it's the right way to do it?  Thx!  As well, if you post an answer, I can give you the credit for that.

Comment: Looks OK to me (but I don't use Helm). If it works, it works. Apparently you found out that the `ARG` in this case is from the prefix argument. If so, you correctly provided that using `interactive`. No need to credit me. You can accept your own answer - nothing wrong with that.

Comment: OK, thanks for reviewing!

Answer (score 0):

Following Drew's piece of advice, this should do it:

```
(defun my/helm-menu (arg)
  "For Org mode buffers, show Org headlines.
For programming mode buffers, show functions, variables, etc."
  (interactive "P")
  (cond ((derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
           (helm-org-in-buffer-headings))
        (t
            (helm-semantic-or-imenu arg))))
```

At least, it works!